# Next router will not work with type NextPage

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to implement dynamic routing in an app that was built with static routes only. I'm confused as I'm running into typescript errors that make no sense to me. I'll include the code here, can someone please help point me as to how to deal with this error?

[Issues I'm running into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSg24.png)

```
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
// import CardWhitData from 'src/components/molecules/cardWhitData';
import FloatCard from 'src/components/atoms/floatCard';

const Event: NextPage = () => (
  const router = useRouter()
  const {index} = router.query
  <>
    <FloatCard
      mainTitle="This is your event"
      description="This is your description"
    />
  </>
)
export default Event;
```

And I get this error:

```
Type '() => (: any, router: NextRouter | undefined, : any, { index }?: boolean) => any' is not assignable to type 'NextPage<{}, {}>'.
  Type '() => (: any, router: NextRouter | undefined, : any, { index }?: boolean) => any' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext<any>): {} | Promise<{}>; }'.
    Type '() => (: any, router: NextRouter | undefined, : any, { index }?: boolean) => any' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
      Type '(: any, router: NextRouter | undefined, : any, { index }?: boolean) => any' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1):

The open `{` and close `}` braces are missing. Also, the `return`. It should be like the following:

```js
const Event: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const {index} = router.query
  return <>
    <FloatCard
      mainTitle="This is your event"
      description="This is your description"
    />
  </>
}
```